# Solve System of linear equations for $y_0, y_1, y_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble solving this for  $y_0, y_1, y_2$. I have tried by hand, matlab, and wolfram. If someone could help me out it would be great. Thanks.

$ln(z_0)=ln(y_0)+(x_0)(y_1)+(x_0)^2(y_2)$

$ln(z_1)=ln(y_0)+(x_1)(y_1)+(x_1)^2(y_2)$

$ln(z_2)=ln(y_0)+(x_2)(y_1)+(x_2)^2(y_2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let $y'_0=\ln y_0$, then what you have is a linear system in $y'_0$, $y_1$ and $y_2$

Comment: syms z0 z1 z2 y0 y1 y2 x0 x1 x2
a=[log(z0);log(z1);log(z2)]
b=[1 x0 x0^2;1 x1 x1^2; 1 x2 x2^2]
c=[log(y0); y1; y2]

inv(b)*a